# Coprime ideals in ring

Tags: ideals

Given the commutative ring R with unity and $a,b,c \in R$, prove that if the following are coprime principal ideals
$$
⟨a⟩=\{\ ar\ |\ r∈R\ \}\  and\  ⟨b⟩=\{\ br\ |\ r∈R\ \}
$$
and $a\ |\ bc$ (a divides bc), then $a\ |\ c$ (a divides c).

I know that I have to show that a and b are "coprime elements".

For example in $ \mathbb{Z}$, the ideals $m \mathbb{Z}$ and $n \mathbb{Z}$ are coprime ideals when $ \mathbb{Z} =  m\mathbb{Z}+ n\mathbb{Z} = GCD(m,n) \mathbb{Z}$ and $GCD(m,n) =  \pm1$. So I understand the concept, but when the ring is arbitrary, I'm not sure how can I prove the statement.

Comment: the GCD only can be 1 for coprimeness

Comment: In the quotient ring $R/\langle a \rangle$, the element $b+\langle a \rangle$ is a unit. Now, use the fact that units are never zero divisors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same as in the case with $\mathbb Z$.  If $I$ and $J$ are coprime ideals of a ring $R$, this means that $I+J = R$.  So in particular, you can write $1 = i+j$ for $i \in I, j\in J$.  Write out what this means for your ideals and a proof  will be readily apparent.

Comment: That was the thing I tried, $ar + bs = 1$, but I'm still stuck on how I get the contradiction. Could you give me a little more details? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Multiply both sides by $c$